# Want to extract all json data and assign to fields

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have a sample json data from which i want to extract all informations which is a mixture of sub araayas also,

```
{
      "imei": "35XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "imei_parts": {
        "fac": "XX",
        "cd": "X",
        "snr": "XXXXXX",
        "tac": "35XXXX"
      },
      "brand": "NOKIA",
      "info": {
        "weight": 130.0,
        "battery": [
          "Li-Ion",
          850
        ],
        "qwerty": false,
        "year": [
          "2002",
          "09"
        ],
        "talk_time_umts": 0.0,
        "stand_by": 200.0,
        "touch_scr": false,
        "size": {
          "width": 57.0,
          "thickness": 26.0,
          "height": 130.0
        },
        "wifi_hotspot": false,
        "cpu_clock": 104.0,
        "other_band": [],
        "build": "Classic",
        "tel_func": false,
        "lan": false,
        "talk_time": 4.0,
        "int_memory": "4",
        "gsm_band": [
          "900",
          "1800",
          "1900"
        ],
        "memory_card": [
          "MMC",
          0
        ],
        "umts_band": [],
        "hsdpa_band": [],
        "display": {
          "color": [
            true,
            "4K"
          ],
          "type": "LCD",
          "size": {
            "width": 176,
            "inches": 2.1,
            "height": 208
          }
        },
        "lan_ports": null,
        "os": "Symbian 6.1",
        "cpu": "ARM9"
      },
      "model": "3650"
    };
```

Want to extract all the information from each and every point of it. All the details are received from an API and will be pushed into my database as well.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: And where is your attempt?You want to do it in `PHP` or `javascript/jQuery`?

Comment: Want to do it in jQuery, i want to assign these to my existing fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have json so yo simply can parse json string.

```
//result -> is return result from api

var parsejson = JSON.parse(result);
```

Now you can access easily like -

```
console.log(parsejson.imei) // 35XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: What if i want to access something inside of an array like from here

"info": {
        "weight": 130.0,
        "battery": [
          "Li-Ion",
          850
        ],

Comment: You can this way parsejson.info.battery

Comment: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @BRAHMANANDAMOHANTYBRAHMA check this link it's working fine here https://jsbin.com/wolidof/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery, this code..

```
  $.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
```

Comment: But how can i extract the values from sub-array and assign them to my fields?

Comment: $.getJSON("url_with_json_here", function(data){
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log(value.imei );     console.log(value.imei_parts);
        });
    });

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at (index):115
    at dispatch (VM256 jquery-1.9.1.js:3074)
    at elemData.handle (VM256 jquery-1.9.1.js:2750)

This is what i got